# What are the low-level RPCs used to create a window on macOS?

Tags: macos, low-level, mach

Here is my understanding of how an application talks with WindowServer:
[image: Application to WindowServer]

Where can I find documentation for the red parts?

For example, I would like to know how NSWindowController manages to create a window. I could not find this in any of the documented APIs (CoreGraphics, QuartzCore, etc). Is there some other API providing this (shown as ??? is the diagram)?

The ideal answer to my question would be a small C program than manages to launch an application by using only low-level RPCs (I do realize that such a program would only work on a single version of macOS if it relies on undocumented APs).

Comment: Everything past the green APIs is undocumented, subject to change, all bets are off, etc. etc. I'm not even sure if you have the code signing entitlements needed for XPC with some processes. Frankly, why could you possibly want to do this? Just as a learning experiment?

Comment: As for your question about creating a window in C, the short answer is you can't, you need to call into Objective-C APIs (although technically using Objective-C is *mostly* possible in pure C).